# Groovy iterating list variables

Tags: groovy

I am working on a script to collect field names (dialogPartyASelection_* && dialogPartyBSelection_*) and then compare the two values to see check if they match. The full list(selections)of fields is being broken down into 'groups' before comparison. I can break out certain parts (IE, comparing the two field values via iteration) and test successfully, however when bringing everything together the script doesn't seem to compare correctly. I may be approaching this/setting myself up to do this wrong, (have started to toy with creating a map, with party A as the key with party B as value).

Snippet of code:

```
    // Test Variables
PartyBSelection_Propertieshamster = 'Accepted'
PartyBSelection_Propertieszembra = 'Agreed'
PartyBSelection_Propertiesdogs = 'Agreed'
PartyBSelection_Propertiescats  = 'Decision taken'
PartyASelection_Propertieshamster = 'Accepted'
PartyASelection_Propertieszembra = 'Agreed'
PartyASelection_Propertiesdogs = 'Agreed'
PartyASelection_Propertiescats = 'Decision taken'
// example of selections(there are lots of entries for A/B party) = ['dialogPartyBSelection_Communication','dialogPartyASelection_Housing','dialogPartyASelection_Income','PartyASelection_Properties']
def selectedGroup = { s -> selections.findAll { it.contains s}} // for pulling groups of questions from list
def isAgreed = { a, b -> (a in ['Agreed', 'Decision taken','Accepted'] && b in ['Agreed', 'Decision taken','Accepted']) } // for comparing values

for(questions in selectedGroup("Properties")){
   {k -> percentCompleteProperties += isAgreed("PartyASelection_${k}", "PartyBSelection_${k}")? 1 : 0}
   println questions
   println percentCompleteProperties
}
```

Current output:

```
PartyBSelection_Propertiescats

0

PartyBSelection_Propertieshamster

0

PartyBSelection_Propertiesdogs

0

PartyBSelection_Propertieshamster

0

PartyASelection_Propertiescats

0

PartyASelection_Propertieshamster

0

PartyASelection_Propertiesdogs

0

PartyASelection_Propertieshamster

0
```

Comment: Hi. What is **selections** ?

Comment: Hi, sorry I have made an edit to add an example. It's the 'master list' I filtering from

Comment: This result of each records have to be "1". (you want)
Is this right?

Comment: Yes, if say (dialogPartyBSelection_Propertiescats && dialogPartyASelection_Propertiescats == 'Decision taken') the result should be 1

Comment: Is "Test Variables" editable? 
and about closure. for example "PartyASelection_${k}" becomes "PartyBSelection_Propertiescats". is this right?

Comment: For testing, yes! These will normally be populated via user input (choice of 1/3 from both sides) so I have just created a few to test with. I think this boils down to being able to reference the value of (PartyBSelection_Propertiescats vs PartyASelection_Propertiescats) dynamically (PartyASelection_/PartyBSelection_ is static)(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is sample code.
but i had changed test data etc.
please check whether this logic is correct for your case.

```
// Test Variables
def testVariables = [
    'PartyBSelection_PropertiesAssets':'Accepted',
    'PartyBSelection_PropertiesDebts': 'Agreed',
    'PartyBSelection_PropertiesMoney': 'Agreed',
    'PartyBSelection_PropertiesSpecialGoods':'Decision taken',
    'PartyASelection_PropertiesAssets':'Accepted',
    'PartyASelection_PropertiesDebts':'Agreed',
    'PartyASelection_PropertiesMoney':'Agreed',
    'PartyASelection_PropertiesSpecialGoods':'Decision taken'
]

List<String> selections= [
    'PropertiesAssets',
    'PropertiesDebts',
    'PropertiesMoney',
    'PropertiesSpecialGoods',
    'PropertiesAssets',
    'PropertiesDebts',
    'PropertiesMoney',
    'PropertiesSpecialGoods'
]


def selectedGroup = { s -> selections.findAll { it.contains s}}
List<String> okLabels = ['Agreed', 'Decision taken','Accepted']
def isAgreed = {a, b ->
    (testVariables[a] in okLabels && testVariables[b] in okLabels)
}

List<Map<String, Integer>> result = selectedGroup("Properties").collect {String question ->
    [(question) : isAgreed("PartyASelection_${question}", "PartyBSelection_${question}")? 1 : 0 ]
}

assert result == [
    ['PropertiesAssets':1],
    ['PropertiesDebts':1],
    ['PropertiesMoney':1],
    ['PropertiesSpecialGoods':1],
    ['PropertiesAssets':1],
    ['PropertiesDebts':1],
    ['PropertiesMoney':1],
    ['PropertiesSpecialGoods':1]
]
```

---

Other way

```
def r = [:]
def questionsCount = selectedGroup("Properties").size()
selectedGroup("Properties").eachWithIndex {String question, Integer i ->
    println "question:${question}(${i+1}/${questionsCount})"
    r.put(question,isAgreed("PartyASelection_${question}", "PartyBSelection_${question}")? 1 : 0 )
}
// This version includes all records in to the one map.
// Also, a record that is duplicated (as key) is overwritten.
r == [PropertiesAssets:1, PropertiesDebts:1, PropertiesMoney:1, PropertiesSpecialGoods:1]
```

then output:

```
question:PropertiesAssets(1/8)
question:PropertiesDebts(2/8)
question:PropertiesMoney(3/8)
question:PropertiesSpecialGoods(4/8)
question:PropertiesAssets(5/8)
question:PropertiesDebts(6/8)
question:PropertiesMoney(7/8)
question:PropertiesSpecialGoods(8/8)
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was trying to achieve, however If i'm trying to avoid maps if possible as the results will only be referenced once (for a running completion %) I can adjust this to work, however would there be a way of approaching this closer to the original code? -

Comment: sorry, i can not understand "if possible as the results will only be referenced once (for a running completion %)" ...

for example, will you show the message like "You have agreed to 60% from the questions" ? is this right?

Comment: Please ignore that, thank you - this makes perfect sense. Would using a map like this be 'best approach' for this situation?

Comment: selections [] will be quite large, I was trying to avoid listing the suffixes as they are already in selectedGroup[] hence the list. I can work with the map, just trying to better understand approach. Thank you so much for your help&knowledge

Comment: That was my approach. of course there are a lot other way. so Groovy is really great programming language! :)
i try write code as functional programming style. also i do not want to update variable as far as possible. i added **Other way** in to the above code. you can this one check too.
`collect` is used for "there is NOT side effect". `each` or `eachWithIndex` is used for "there is side effect".My English is not good. if you can not understand, sorry.

Comment: Thank you for your help, this makes a of sense. I'm really looking to compare the values of PartyASelection_X with PartyBSelection_X, if these hold the same value, I just need +1 in a list (I can use this for % complete).